# Is android-keystore's password empty?

Tags: android, cmd, keystore, android-keystore

I tried this command on Android Studio's terminal:

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Shehar Yar Khan\.android\debug.keystore"
```

But wasn't able to enter the password. In fact, the keyboard was **stuck** on terminal (and does the same on Command Prompt), but was working fine on Chrome and other applications. So, I tried pressing the "Enter" key and this is what I was presented with:

```
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
* The integrity of the information stored in your keystore  *
* has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *
* you must provide your keystore password.                  *
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************

Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Mar 3, 2019
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
Issuer: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
Serial number: 1
Valid from: Sun Mar 03 22:05:35 PKT 2019 until: Tue Feb 23 22:05:35 PKT 2049
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  Something... Something... Something...
         SHA1: Something... Something... Something...
         SHA256: And yet again... Something... Something... Something...

Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 1024-bit RSA key
Version: 1

Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an indu
stry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Users\Shehar Yar Khan\.android\
debug.keystore -destkeystore C:\Users\Shehar Yar Khan\.android\debug.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12
".
```

So, how can I prevent the keyboard from getting stuck on `Enter Keystore Password:`

I am new to android programming and working on Flutter. So, I don't know if there's something else I need to include with the question.

I tried looking for other answers on StackOverFlow, but couldn't find any that could help with my situation. Oh! And aren't the keys supposed to be protected by a default password like "android"?

Comment: no keystore password is not empty ,when you are creating keystore that time you add password in it. enter that password here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The keyboard is not actually stuck, it's just not displaying the password. Just enter the password as that prompt pops up and enter the password.

Android Studio's default debug keystore's password is "android"